# How can I merge referenced assembly into single .dll for Dynamics CRM plugin?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, openxml-sdk, ilmerge

I've followed every guide I could find related to `ILMerge` in order to merge a third party .dll into a custom Dynamics CRM plugin (.dll) so that I may use the functionality.

I am writing a Dynamics CRM plugin that will take a .docx document, populate some information, and add an annotation (Note) to an associated entity.  Retrieving the document template and creating an annotation work fine. so, I know my plugin is sound (registers and runs okay).

However, once I attempt to use `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` to manipulate my document template, I get an error that Dynamics CRM:

> Could not load file or assembly 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.5.5631.0......."

After doing some research, I found that I needed to "merge" the `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll` into my plugin .dll.

I installed `MSBuild.ILMerge.Task` (and ILMerge) in VS2015.  During the build process, I now get two messages "Transitive merge" and "Merged assemblies:  *pathname*\my.dll; *pathname*\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll".  It seemed to do what I needed. However, when I update the plugin with the new .dll, I get the same "*Could not load file or assembly*" error message.

I am unable to find any documentation that could further help in ensuring that my referenced DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll actually gets merged into my target .dll.

Comment: Instead of updating the existing plugin in PRT, unregister the existing & register the new assembly with merged dll

Comment: You can use any decompiler to see the content of merged dll & verify

Comment: @ArunVinoth, I deleted my .dll and rebuilt it.  I used dotPeek to check the .dll to make sure it included the DocumentFormat.OpenXml assembly.  I then unregistered and re-registered the .dll in Plugin Registration Tool and it all worked!  If you want to post an Answer for unregistering and to re-register the .dll, I'll mark it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am unable to find any documentation that could further help in ensuring that my referenced DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll actually gets merged into my target .dll.

You can use any decompiler (ex: dotPeek) to see the content of merged dll & verify.

> when I update the plugin with the new .dll, I get the same "Could not load file or assembly" error message.

Instead of updating the existing plugin in PRT, unregister the existing & register the new assembly with merged dll.